# JQuery Mobile vs. CustomMobileViewEngine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am looking at Scott Hanselman's CustomMobileViewEngine pattern found here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx

This lets mvc know what device you are on, so you can create layouts for each device so each device gets scaled correctly in a given device.

JQuery Mobile seems to automatically scale to any device out of the box.

My confusion is why are people using both together aren't they achieving the samething?

I am looking to create a simple mobile site that has 2 pages (a static page and a page that contains a gridview) and a master page.

My other confusion is if I use jquery mobile can I create the grid view out using an html table or do I have to create it using a jquery mobile control?

I am looking at my MVC project and I have a folder under views for 3 Index pages (1 for iphone, ipad, android) but all the pages are the same html the only difference is the rendering of the page in different devices. 
Am I suppose to have 3 of the same page? I think something is wrong with my design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think some people use it to display more content based on the device. For example if it is iphone, they might limit the content to the most important stuff. If it is ipad, they can inject some more content.

you can create the grid view using just html as long as it has the right "data-" attributes.